# how to call EditText onSelectionChanged method in Activity in Android studio

Tags: android

How to use onSelectionChanged in Activity. I have created different class extending EditText and overridden onSelectionChanged. Its working there but i want to use this onSelectionChanged method in activity

```
public EditTextCursorWatcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

public EditTextCursorWatcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public EditTextCursorWatcher(Context context) {
    super(context);

}


 @Override   
 protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) { 
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "selStart is " + selStart + "selEnd is " + selEnd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

Step Two: refer to the class in the layout file (eg main.xml (though mine was a custom dialog layout)). Don't forget to use full package name (in this case com.example.EditTextCursorWatcher, eg

```
<com.example.EditTextCursorWatcher
 android:id="@+id/etEdit"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="top"
android:minLines="5"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

I want to call this onSelectionChanged function in MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
etEdit.setAccessibilityDelegate(object : View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
        override fun sendAccessibilityEvent(host: View?, eventType: Int) {
            super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType)
            if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED{
                 //TODO
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your own listener interface.

```
  @Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd){

    for(ISelectionChangedListener listener : selectionChangedListeners){
        listener.selectionChanged("...");
    }
    super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
}


private ArrayList<ISelectionChangedListener> selectionChangedListeners = new ArrayList<>();

public void addOnSelectionChangedListener(ISelectionChangedListener listener){
    selectionChangedListeners.add(listener);
}

public interface ISelectionChangedListener{
    void selectionChanged(String newSelection);
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference